# как можно перебрать многомерный массив

Tags: php, codeigniter

В контроллер приходит массив вот такого вида, количество записей емайлов и телефонов не ограниченно, их может быть и 5 и 10. Как можно его перебрать так, чтобы дальше я мог обращаться к элементам нового массива например так `$newarr['email'][$i]['login']` потому что я хочу сделать валидацию под каждую конкретную новую строчку, то есть это будет выглядеть примерно так `if(!empty($newarr['email'][$i]['login']) || !empty($newarr['email'][$i]['pass']){ и здесь уже валидация }` пробовал вложенными циклами, но так и не получилось добиться нужного результата, поэтому прошу помочь

```
Array
(
[uid] => 2
[ajaxRequest] => 1
[email] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [login] => test@mail.ru
                [pass] => sdvsadd
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [login] => test@yandex.ru
                [pass] => dfsadfsadfdsaf
            )

    )

[phone] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [pu_login] => eqwe
                [pu_pass] => 123
                [pu_numeric] => 343
                [pu_sip] => zxczx
            )

    )
```

)

Comment: А что мешает сейчас обратится точно таким же способом к уже существующему массиву?
`$arr['email'][$i]['login']` ?

Comment: или использовать `foreach($newarr["email"] as $key => $arItem)`

Comment: Перебрать можно любым из циклов. Например foreach. А в чем проблема? Сделайте цикл в цикле. Что именно нужно сделать? Напишите что пробовали!

Comment: благодарю за помощь, действительно, нужно было всего лишь перебирать  `$array['email']` и `$array['phone']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут все просто ведь:

```
foreach($array['email'] as $email){
 // обращаетесь $email['login'] || $email['pass']

}
```